# Convert flac to m4a at 400Kps?

Tags: sound, music, file-format, aac, m4a

It's worth a try, I love linux and I have so many years using it but now there's only one thing that I cannot do. I have my music collection in flac and I always convert flac to m4a using nero aac under Windows but in Linux I don't know how to do it. With sound-converter and soundkonverter I only get 256kbs aac files and I want them at 400kbs for the sound quality and space.

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing it on Windows, with Nero AAC?

If you use `neroAacEnc -lc -br 400 -if <input-file> -of <output-file>` on Windows, then it's  the same on Linux with the Linux binaries that Nero offers.

You should re-evaluate your choice of encoder, codec and bitrate:

- Mobile and entertainment devices today have more storage space, integration to online storage or streaming and support for lossless audio formats. Why not go with FLAC for the important pieces and use 256kbps for everything else?
- There are new encoders and codecs like [Fraunhofer FDK AAC](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC) and [Opus](https://www.opus-codec.org/).
- At last, have you ever made a double-blind test with different AAC encoders and your Nero 400kbps encodes? Do you notice any difference? On which playback device and which gear?

Related:

- [How to convert AC3 6ch audio to HE-AAC? GUI solution?](https://askubuntu.com/q/185485/40581)

Answer (score 1):

`neroAacEnc` will not use flac as an *input* file but you can use Linux *pipes* to pass the file to `neroAacEnc` using either `ffmpeg` or `avconv`. To achieve your *slightly outrageous bitrate* use the following:

```
ffmpeg -i test.flac -f wav - | neroAacEnc -if - -ignorelength -br 400000 -of test.m4a
```

This tested nicely on my own system and should work as well with `avconv` if you prefer to use this instead of `ffmpeg`. The `avconv` syntax differes only in the name of the executable:

```
avconv -i test.flac -f wav - | neroAacEnc -if - -ignorelength -br 400000 -of test.m4a
```

I confess that the monstrous bitrate could perhaps grow on me as well :)

**References:**

- [Hydrogenaudio wiki: Nero AAC](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Nero_AAC)